# Setting form text inputs to geolocation latitude and longitude using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a multipage mobile app, hopefully just two pages, and want to put geolocation latitude and longitude into two separate form text inputs. I would like this to happen on a button push or tap.

I really don't know how to:

1. Target the form text input field
2. Write the function

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="GPS Location">GPS Lat</label>
    <input name="GPS Lat" id="GPSlat" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="GPS Location">GPS Long</label>
    <input name="GPS Long" id="GPSlong" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
        { 
            var lat = pos.coordinates.latitude;
            var lng = pos.coordinates.longitude;
            console.log( lat + ":" + lng);
        });
    </script>
</div>

<input value="SetGPS" id="SetGPS" data-inline="true" type="submit">
<br>
<div data-role="content">
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $("#SetGPS").click(function(){
        $("#GPSlat input").text(lat);
        $("#GPSlong input").text(lng)
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: So which part isn't working? Also, note that you should be closing your input and br tags: `<input ... />`, `<br />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just made a few name and syntax errors:

- The function you made for `getCurrentPosition` takes a parameter called `position`, but you refer to `pos` inside it.
- `lat` and `lng` are defined inside the above function, so they're not available to the `click` function
- You refer to `coordinates`, but the field [is actually called `coords`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition).
- You're setting the text of the input fields, but you should be setting the value
- Your input selectors are incorrect. They should be `input#id`
- Your click function is missing closing braces and brackets.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
var lat, lng;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
{ 
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log( lat + ":" + lng);
});

// ...

$("#SetGPS").click(function()
{
    $("input#GPSlat").val(lat);
    $("input#GPSlong").val(lng);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Simon. I tried it and it worked like a charm. I'll pay this forward and try to get on a better structured learning program as far as this Jquery and Jquery mobile goes. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: No worries! I'd recommend, however, just learning more about JavaScript and css to start with - JQuery is just a helper library.